# Prove for every $k\geq1$ there exist $n$ that satisfies $2^n = -2^k$ (mod $10^k$).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove for every $k\geq1$ there exist $n$ that satisfaest $2^n = -2^k$ (mod $10^k$).

By simply trying I saw this is correct but I have no idea how to prove it.

Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: by the Chinese remainder theorem, $2^n\equiv -2^k\pmod{10^k}$ if and only if both $2^n\equiv -2^k\pmod{2^k}$ and $a\equiv b\pmod{5^k}$. Given $k$, can you choose $n$ to satisfy these last two congruences simultaneously?

Comment: @GregMartin If I understand, every $n>k$?

Comment: For $k=1$, $n=3$ would work, so $k>1$ should be replaced with $k \ge 1$.

Comment: @GregMartin But what is $a$ and $b$ in second equation?

Comment: Typo, sorry, $a=2^n$ and $b=-2^k$.

Comment: @GregMartin I still can't prove there exist such n

Comment: Further hint: prove that $2^n\equiv-2^k\pmod{2^k}$ for any $n\ge k$; and prove that there exists a positive integer $j$ such that $2^j\equiv-1\pmod{5^k}$ (this is the hardest step), from which it follows that $2^{j+k}\equiv-2^k\pmod{5^k}$.

Comment: @GregMartin I understand all you said in comment, I'm struggling to prove there exist $j$ so $2^j=-1$ (mod $5^k$).

Comment: Can you prove that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $5^k$? How does that help?

Comment: @GregMartin I know how that will help me, but don't know how to prove 2 is primitive root?

Comment: At this point, the best help I can give you is to suggest that you go review or learn standard results about primitive roots modulo odd prime powers. I wouldn't expect someone to invent all those proofs themselves (though great if they do!), but this task turns out to be extremely straightforward given the background that is already known to us.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you for your help! I found out way is 2 primitive root for $5^k$.
See link: https://exploringnumbertheory.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/primitive-roots-of-powers-of-odd-primes/